# Adding Frameworks Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode5.1

How do you add frameworks in the new Xcode version 5.1? Now when you select your project file within Xcode at the top I only see 2 tabs now.. Info tab and  Build Settings. The previous versions there was a general tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between editing the *project* and editing the *target*. You are editing the project; edit the target instead. Nothing has changed here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry thats what I meant I am editing the target? I have the top file selected like I always do to add a framework

Comment: The "top file" can mean the project or the target. You are editing the project. Switch to the target.

Comment: There is little menu at the top left that lets you switch between the project and the various targets.